# Delphi 7 / Indy 9 app not connecting to Apache via SSL

Tags: apache, delphi, ssl, openssl, indy

We have an app built in Delphi 7 using Indy 9 for https connections to a php back end running on PHP, on Linux.  The app connects to our current production server without a problem.  We have been building a test environment for this application in house, and on the test web server, it refuses to connect using https.  The app HAS been able to connect to this server using http.  I can connect any current browser using the same web calls the app makes (haven't tried older browsers), and I get the connection, and the data returs perfectly, so apparently a there's something in Indy 9 holding this up from working (which is why this question is here and not on ServerFault)  Does anyone have enough experience with Indy / SSL to know what's happening here?

Here are the few differences I thought might have some input:
1. I was initially starting with a wildcard cert.  It is valid, and on the correct domain.  It works with everything else we have on lots of servers.
2. Thinking it was possible that wildcard certs are a newer thing than Indy 9, I removed the wildcard cert, and put in a self signed cert, with the full machine name.  It failed in the same way.  BUT, as you know, browsers issue a cert exception with these self signed certs, so I was unsure if this would ALSO give Indy problems.
3. I'm sure the version of OpenSSH on our new development server is newer than the one that is currently on our production server.  I can dig out these exact versions if someone thinks it will help.

This is an app I inherited, so my knowledge of SSL and Indy is limited.  This app is at the end of it's life, so upgrading to Indy 10 is not something my company is going to fund.  Any help or pointers or hints are extremely welcome, and my thanks would be infinite.
Thank you so much Stackers!

Comment: Did you set some breakpoints or put some OutputDebugString or CodeSite log messages in?  You should at least detail what you found out from doing that about what error is happening. "Not connecting?" How?

Answer (score 3):

There's no mention of the specific error that is going on, so to offer suggestions without the particular error message is difficult.

1) Track down the actual responses you are receiving in the SSL handshake and try to make heads or tails of the messages.  (DoStatusInfo())

2) (Big guesss here) SSL connectivity comes in different versions where the older versions are out of date and no longer recommended to be supported. If you are building a new server, it likely has defaults that are different than the current production machine which I'm assuming to be a much older build. (The older it is, the more applicable this guess is.)  The newer servers should hopefully be refusing to connect to SSL V2 and V3 (and only allowing TLS)  So it could be the difference of configuration of old production server and new test server and this new one is filtering out the older SSL versions and preventing the handshake to continue. (Which would be shown in handshake failures in #1 which is your real tool to use to answer this question.)

Here's a quick test of connectivity using openssl.exe.  Try this connection to the test box and to the production machine to see if the connection is made.  You can try v3 as well to either verify or eliminate this guess...if they act the same, then concentrate on #1.   :)

```
openssl s_client -ssl2 -connect yourhost:443
```

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling the `sslvrfPeer` flag in the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.VerifyMode` property and then return `True` in the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.OnVerifyPeer` event.